# Reset Angular Form extensions after submit

Tags: angularjs

I'm using Angular Agility Form extension for validation of my form. 
It works pretty well until I try to reset the form after the submit.

I can reset the fields but Form extension show the error message for each fields.

```
My controller code : myApp.controller("myCtrl1", ['$scope', function ($scope)      {
   $scope.save = function(){
   alert($scope.myName);
   $scope.myName = ""; // Reset the field

   }
}
```

See fiddler here : http://jsfiddle.net/05hq7shr/101/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the official documentation:

https://github.com/AngularAgility/AngularAgility

You have to pass on the form.

```
<button aa-submit-form="save(exampleForm)" class="btn btn-default">Save</button>
```

And then call $reset.

```
exampleForm.$aaFormExtensions.$reset(true);
```

`true` - no confirmation before reset

`false` - confirmation before reset

You won't see the message now. But you'll have to fix the css that you have added to remove the red border.

Check this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/05hq7shr/102/